# show all page options without gap in kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I am trying to get all page options to show without ellipsis "gap" like this:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 12

and more like this

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

regardless of the number of pages.

I've fussed with the kaminari views to no end and I don't see anything in the config options.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the "outer_window" option in config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb.  Example:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.outer_window = 12
end
```

Comment: It seems to max out at 10 for me

Answer (score 0):

In Kaminari version 1.2.1 and above, it seems like you can provide a `window` option to the `paginate` helper method. So to get all of the page links, without clipping, you can do:

```
<%= paginate @collection, window: @collection.total_pages %>
```